# GTK3 API: Replacement for deprecated gtk_text_freeze API?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gnome

I want to make a new application with the GTK3 API. I want to use the old GTK API described in the textbook from my lecturer. The old API is `gtk_text_freeze`. I have read the Gtk documentation on the Gnome website, and I find that the API has been deprecated, but it does not explain the replacement of the API.

So. Do you know a replacement for that API?

Comment: Well, looking at the GTK doc, I read *"Freezes the GtkText widget which disallows redrawing of the widget until it is thawed. This is useful if a large number of changes are going to made to the text within the widget, reducing the amount of flicker seen by the user."*. And looking at `gtk_text_thaw` that's also deprecated. My guess is that this function has no replacement and is just deprecated because the functionality has been removed/optimized.

Comment: Ya... I also had time to think like that. but @jussiKukkonen explained well about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GtkText was deprecated ~18 years ago ... I wonder when the lecture material was last updated?

The typical way to prevent update flicker is to call `g_object_freeze_notify()` on your data source (like a GtkTextBuffer), then do the updates you are going to do, then call `g_object_thaw_notify ()`. This isn't really a "replacement" for gtk_text_freeze() since what it did was stupid: you don't want to stop redrawing the widget, you just want the new data to appear atomically.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I was also surprised to see it in their deprecated API history. BTW I have found the answer. I just forgot to update this question. Thank you very much for helping. 

I will mark your answer as the best. For now.

Comment: ~18 years ago -- well holy s**t.

Comment: Great news guys, [GtkText is back in upcoming GTK+  4](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/GtkText.html) ;-)